# How do you use the Azure Media Services REST API?

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-media-services

All of the examples I find for building apps with Azure Media Services are using the .NET Azure Media Services SDK. Are there any reliable examples anywhere that showcase how to consume their REST APIs?

The reason I'm asking is that I need to leverage the services in Xamarin, and we can't use the .NET Azure Media Services SDK because it would not be portable across all three major mobile OSes.

Comment: I wrote some blog posts some time ago on consuming Media Service REST API which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/tag/windows-azure-media-service/. The sample code is in C# but it should give you some ideas about porting it in other languages.

Comment: @GauravMantri, the link you supplied is broken. Is there a new one we can use to get to your article? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for examples consuming REST API in .NET?
General rest API references located at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973617.aspx.

You can find examples of REST requests for various azure media services scenarios under MSDN section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973629.aspx